# Grassmann and Stiefel manifolds

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, stiefel-manifolds

I want to show these two objects live up to their name in the sense that they actually are manifolds. The Grassmann manifold I understand to be a generalization of projective space (everything is done over $\mathbb R$ here), where we consider $k$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$, while the Stiefel manifold is defined as the space of all $k$-frames in this same space. By a $k$-frame I mean an ordered set of $k$ linearly independent vectors.

I have already been able to show that the Grassmann manifold actually is a manifold by using a few properties of topological manifolds to prove Hausdorf property and second-countability.

On one hand, I feel like it should be possible to go through a highly similar process to check all the conditions for the Stiefel manifold. On the other hand, it is pretty easy to see there exists a natural relationship between these manifolds - every $k$-frame spans a $k$-dimensional linear space, and so every element of a Stiefel manifold can be associated in this way with a matrix (and hence an equivalence class of these matrixes) in the Grassmann manifold.

Is there a way I can use this relationship to make short work of this question? It feels like a natural thing to do, but I don't quite see how. My study of manifolds and differential geometry is just starting, so I don't have many tools yet, just the basic properties of smooth manifolds and differentiable structures.

Comment: I missed the word 'ordered'. Other than that, this is the definition in my book.

Comment: oh! That's a typo.

Comment: Your Stiefel manifold is an **open** subset $S\subset M_{n\times k}(\mathbb R)\cong \mathbb R^{kn}$, so it is trivially a manifold of dimension $n\cdot k$. The subset is determined by the condition that a $n\times k$ matrix is in $S$ iff  one of its $k\times k$ minor  is non-zero.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to see it's open. I should show that the linearly dependent matrixes are a closed set then?

Comment: Try with $2\times 2$ and then $3\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Okay well for the square matrixes, I think it's like this:

the determinant is a continuous function of several variables which has input in the set of matrixes, and output in the real numbers. Since $\mathbb R - {0}$ is open, by continuity, the set of non-singular square matrixes is open.

Comment: For the nonsquare ones, maybe I can say something similar, but consider the submatrixes. Define a function which accepts n x p matrixes as inputs, but is basically just the determinant on the submatrixes. Each is continuous since det is continuous, and so the inverse image of the open set as above is n x p matrixes, but not all are linearly independent, although they are open. But if we define one of these for every submatrix, their intersection gives the desired result.